# Authorization issue when uploading image to the s3 bucket using Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have used the code below for uploading an image to the s3 bucket using Android.

```
AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(context.getString(R.string.accesskey),context.getString(R.string.secretkey)));
PutObjectResult result = s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, amazonfilepath, file).withAccessControlList(acl));
```

When I create bucket in Asia Pacific (Singapore) regions then it works fine.
But I have to change regions of bucket to Asia Pacific (Mumbai) then it throws below error.

> Amazon s3 image
>   uploading:com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The
>   authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use
>   AWS4-HMAC-SHA256. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
>   InvalidRequest; Request ID: 85D0346520B14007), S3 Extended Request ID:
>   gC67avqeowqS4+X+2qkBxzLxfj9ABVV22zWgPcm/rZBKC0RIso201+eMsvBsqdnH+8n0V9RI0J8=

Comment: Hi, What is your usecase of using BasicAWSCredentials? Using hard coded credentials in the app is very dangerous and not recommended. Can you use Cognito Identity instead? It is a free service and designed specifically for mobile use cases. 

Also, can you mention what SDK version you are using? Did you try using AWSS3TransferUtility? That is easy to use for achieving simple upload usecase.

Comment: Hi Rohan Thanks for ans,
I was used 2.2.13  SDK version for same. and Cognito Identity is not supported in Asia Pacific (Mumbai). right now i have used 2.4.0 sdk version and problem is solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was used below SDK for same.

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.13'
```

now used below version of sdk than it will work fine.

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed, Updating the sdk to latest version fixed it. in my case,

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.6.13'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.13'
```

if you have the same issue, check the aws sdk version in your app level build.gradle file.

Just answering incase someone comes here searching for it.